# Get the format of date | Swift | iOS

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

As per the requirement, my API might return date in either "2018-01-01" or "01-01-2018" or "2018-01-01T00:00:00" format

How can I check the format of the date?

eg: my code for API response "2018-01-01" should return me "yyyy-MM-dd" etc..

I can do this by checking length of my characters and by assigning date format accordingly..but i feel this is not the right approach.

Comment: What are the timeZones of your dates? Are they UTC?

Comment: What is the format of your second date `"01-01-2018"`? `"MM-dd-yyyy"` or `"dd-MM-yyyy"`?

Comment: If you are absolutely positive that the dates will be in one of 3 known formats then the approach in Leo's answer will work, but this is a really bad situation. Why would the API you are using provide dates in 3 different formats without any tags to tell which is which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define your date formats and try each of them. One of them will succeed. Just make sure all your date strings are from the same timezone (I suppose they are all UTC) and don't forget to set the date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" when working with fixed format dates:

```
let dateStrings = ["2018-01-01", "01-01-2018", "2018-01-01T00:00:00"]
let dateFormats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd", "MM-dd-yyyy"]
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
var dates: [Date] = []
for dateString in dateStrings {
    for dateFormat in dateFormats {
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            dates.append(date)
            print("dateFormat:", dateFormat)
            print("date:", date)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> dateFormat: yyyy-MM-dd
>
> date: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>
> dateFormat: MM-dd-yyyy
>
> date: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>
> dateFormat: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>
> date: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Given the requirement, your answer lets the OP convert the input string into a Date, but that's not what he asked. He asked how to return the date string that was able to parse the date. You'd need to refactor this code slightly for that: "print("format for '\(dateString)' is '\(dateFormat)'." And perhaps structure it as a function that returns the date format that works.

Comment: That would be really easy. All he needs is to get the dateFormat after appending the date.

Comment: Yup. It would be trivial to refactor you answer slightly into a function that takes a string date as input and returns the format string that works as output. As you mention in your comments, though, we can't tell which part of the sample dates is the month and which part is the day.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't think OP need to know the date format. He asked that just to be able to parse the date string which it is already shown in my answer. If he actually needs that he can figure it out on his own just by looking at my code.

Comment: He did say 'my code for API response "2018-01-01" should return me "yyyy-MM-dd" etc..' That's pretty explicit. The question isn't super-clear, and as you say the OP SHOULD be able to refactor your code to give that result without a lot of effort.

Comment: @DuncanC : I meant that if the date that i get from my API is 2018-01-25'T'00:00:00, output should be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:SS

Comment: @Ashh, Leo's answer gives you everything you need to write that function, with only minor changes.

Comment: Ya i got it @DuncanC : I was just rephrasing my question. Thank you :)

Comment: You should go back and edit your question to make it clearer. It's quite painful for other people to follow a long stream of comments in order to figure out the real meaning of a question.

Comment: plese help, How to formate this string to Date.     "Tue Mar 12 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)"

Answer (score 0):

It's risky to have ambiguous date formats in an API. But if you are stuck with this you could make multiple `DateFormatters` and configure each for a specific format (by setting their `dateFormat` accordingly) and attempt to convert the string using each of these in turn. Once you have a success, you know which format you got (it's `dateFormat`).